# How do use a <li> for a jquery hover selector?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list that I want to change its contents when I hover over them. Why is this not working? I can use the  id as a selector and it triggers the hover function but then the list items all change color, not just the one I want. I can't use the individual id's either because they're created dynamically. Here is a snipet of the relevant jquery.

```
for (var i=0;i < count; i++)
    {   
        if (i == 4) {break;}
        var elemId = resultsTemp[i].split('.')[0];
        var elemName = resultsTemp[i].split('.')[1];                
        addToList += '<li id="'+elemId+'" class= "profResultsName">'+elemName+'</li>';
    }
        $("#professorDropDown").append(addToList);
```

And Here's another

```
$(".profResultsName").hover(function() 
{
    $(this).css("color","white");
},
function () 
{
    $(this).css("color","black");
});
```

Here's the relevant html.

```
<ul id="professorDropDown" class="addContainer"></ul>
```

Comment: Is there a typo when you add the class to the new li element? Think it should have class=...

Comment: @supertopi seems so. with that fixed it works fine.

Comment: The typo was specific to this site, I'll fix it. I have it correct on my end but it doesn't work.

Comment: May I suggest that it would be neater to remove the `if (i==4)` test from the first line inside your loop and instead have something like `for (var i=0; i < count && i < 4; i++)`.

Comment: I only want the list to be 4 items long at the most and the results come from a mysql query. If only one item is returned will my loop create empty list items if I do that or not create them? I can't know how many items will be returned with the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are two problems a missing `=` in `class"profResultsName"` and handling of dynamic elements

```
for (var i=0;i < count; i++)
{   
    if (i == 4) {break;}
    var elemId = resultsTemp[i].split('.')[0];
    var elemName = resultsTemp[i].split('.')[1];                
    addToList += '<li id="'+elemId+'" class="profResultsName">'+elemName+'</li>';//= missing after class
}
    $("#professorDropDown").append(addToList);
```

then

```
$('#professorDropDown').on('mouseenter', 'li.profResultsName', function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'red')
}).on('mouseleave', 'li.profResultsName', function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'green')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/34KEb/)

Comment: That didn't work. `$(".profResultsName")` is actually the class of the `<li>`

Comment: So what is the diference in application from what I did and using the "on" function? Is one better than the other?

Comment: @CraigPatrickLafferty the `hover` method is a shortcut for registering `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event handlers. when you use `hover` it registers the handler to only those elements which are present in the dom at that point of execution. what I have done is to use event delegation to handle element which are added later using scripting

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation. so use "on" everytime i generate html on the fly? Does this also apply to functions such as click() and fadein(), because I neeh to also be able to click these list items.

Comment: @CraigPatrickLafferty it applies to event handlers like `click`, `change` etc... `fadeIn`, `fadeOut` are not event handlers so it does not applies to them

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. The people on this website are more helpful than my college profs.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should use:

```
$("#professorDropDown").on('hover', 'li', function () {
    $(this).css("color","white");
});
```

Because, you're generating list items on the fly, not on page load.
And I suggest to use classes instead of applying CSS styles directly by JS.

Comment: Classes? I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: I mean, you shouldn't use `$(this).css('"color","white")`, but `$(this).addClass('color-white')`. That's much faster and has better perfomance.

Comment: What's the difference? does it buffer the two states versus creating it every time? also, should I only use it when adding on the fly or for all?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that you're adding a listener for a `ul` element, not `li`.

Since the li is generated on the fly, use this code:

```
for (var i=0;i < 4; i++) {             
    $(".profResults").append('<li  class"profResultsName">item</li>');
    listen();
}

function listen() {
    $(".profResults li").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("color","white");
}, function () {
    $(this).css("color","black");
});
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Mqfx8/